# How to determine if a number is the largest element in a list - Using Racket

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, racket

I'm trying to write a function for peaks which consumes list to produce a sublist that consists of all the peaks of the original list. ex. (peaks (cons 1 (cons 6 (cons 4 (cons 5 empty))))) should produce (cons 6 (cons 5 empty))

MY answer seems right but I think I messed up somewhere because it's not the right answer. I did a helper function using recursion to determine the maximum number in the list and then subbed that into another recursion function to create a sublist consisting of maximum numbers.

Any advice on where I messed up? We just started learning recursions and this is the only question that tripping me up.

````
  (cond
    [(empty? (rest lon)) (first lon)]
    [else (max (first lon) (greatest (rest lon)))]))
 

(define (peaks lon)
  (cond 
    [(empty? (rest lon)) lon]
    [(equal? (first lon) (greatest lon)) (cons (first lon) (peaks (rest lon)))]
    [else (peaks (rest lon))]))```
````

Comment: Does this need recursion? All you want to do is for each element, save it if it's greater than the number before it, and greater than the number after it. You might need recursion to iterate over the list, I don't remember if racket lets you iterate over a list without recursion. Your base cases should take care of the first and last element, the first element just needs to be greater than the one after it, the last number needs to do the same. Also water water water

Comment: @SatbirKira a list is a recursive data structure and so a recursive procedure to handle it is the most natural solution.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is:

```
(define (peaks lst)
  (cond [(empty? lst) lst]
        [(empty? (rest lst)) lst]
        [(empty? (rest (rest lst))) (list (max (first lst) (second lst)))]
        [(<= (first lst) (second lst)) (peaks (rest lst))]
        [else (cons (first lst) (peaks (rest (rest lst))))]))
```

Examples:

```
> (peaks '(1 6 4 5))
'(6 5)

> (peaks '(9 1 2 6 7 3 4 5 0 8))
'(9 7 5 8)

> (peaks '())
'()

> (peaks '(7))
'(7)

> (peaks '(7 3))
'(7)

> (peaks '(3 4))
'(4)

> (peaks '(5 0 8))
'(5 8)

> (peaks '(6 7 3))
'(7)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might approach it like this. First I write a function `is-peak` which determines if three (3) adjacent elements contain a peak in the middle element -

```scm
(define (is-peak a b c)
  (and (< a b) (> b c)))
```

Then I write a `peaks` procedure using pattern match for lists containing elements 0, 1, 2, 3, or more elements -

```scm
(define (peaks ls)
  (match ls
    ;; 0, 1, or 2-element lists do not have peaks
    [(list) null]
    [(list a) null]
    [(list a b) null]

    ;; 3-element lists could have at most 1 peak
    [(list a b c)
     (if (is-peak a b c)
         (list b)
         null)]
    
    ;; 4 elements or more
    [(list a b c d ...)
     (if (is-peak a b c)
         (cons b (peaks (cddr ls)))
         (peaks (cdr ls)))]))
```

```scm
(peaks (list 1 2 1 3 4 5 4 2 1 5 6 7 4))
```

```scm
'(2 5 7)
```

We can visualize the linear process and track the values of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d ...`. Notice how `cddr` allows us to fast-forward one element after a peak is found. This is because a peak can never be adjacent to another peak -

| a | b | c | d... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **2** (peak) | 1 | 3 4 5 4 2 1 5 6 7 4 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 4 2 1 5 6 7 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 4 2 1 5 6 7 4 |
| 4 | **5** (peak) | 4 | 2 1 5 6 7 4 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 5 6 7 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 6 7 4 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 7 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 4 |
| 6 | **7** (peak) | 4 |  |

Now we'll consider some other inputs for `peaks` -

```scm
(peaks (list 1 2 3 2 1))
(peaks (list 3 2 1 2 3))
(peaks null)
```

```scm
'(3)
'()
'()
```